# Why does using a bash variable in find fail?

Tags: bash, find

I've got a find command in a bash script that works, but when I try to break it into variables that get added together it no longer works correctly.

I'm not really looking for a better way of doing this, I'd like to understand what Bash is doing in this case as I'm very stumped at this.

```
# Works, prints ./config
find . -type f -name 'config' ! -path './.git*'

echo
pathVar="! -path './.git*'"
# Doesn't correctly ignore './.git/config'
find . -type f -name 'config' $pathVar

echo
# Doesn't work 'find: ! -path './.git*': unknown primary or operator'
find . -type f -name 'config' "$pathVar"
```

Comment: No, you can't do it simply like that. `$pathVar` is assumed to be a single argument. you may either use `eval` to execute a string as a command or better yet, run the complete commands using conditional checks to decide which command the execute.

Comment: What defines a 'single argument'? Would it just be a string value with no spaces?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments,

Option 1:

```
cmd="find . -type f -name 'config'"
if [[<condition to run long command>]]; then
    cmd="$cmd ! -path './.git*'"
fi
eval $cmd
```

Option 2:

```
if [[<condition to run long command>]]; then
    find . -type f -name 'config' ! -path './.git*'
    # ...
else
    find . -type f -name 'config'
    # ...
fi
```

Comment: What if the `pathVar` from my original question isn't something constant (user input, result from another process etc). How could I build up this find command dynamically?

Comment: Never mind, I can just `cmd="$cmd $pathVar"` to get that behavior with a dynamic variable.